# Using apply function: getting NA values in return as list of values appears non.numeric

Tags: r, apply

I have a list of values as output:

```
               [,1]         [,2]         [,3]        
ATE_true      numeric,1000 numeric,1000 numeric,1000
ate_now       numeric,1000 numeric,1000 numeric,1000
ate_truew     numeric,1000 numeric,1000 numeric,1000
ate_estw      numeric,1000 numeric,1000 numeric,1000
ci_w          numeric,1000 numeric,1000 numeric,1000
```

I want to get mean of each 1000 values i.e. mean(ATE_true[,1], ATE_true[,2]... and so on. Hence used apply function

```
apply(output,1:2,mean)
```

But I am getting in return NA values with the error:
**In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA**

I understand as output is in list format its considering as non- numeric , but how do I solve this?

My desired output:

```
               [,1]  [,2] [,3]
ATE_true       0.98  0.94 0.97
ate_now        0.86  0.85 0.88
ate_truew      0.83  0.87 0.85
ate_estw       0.86  0.89 0.90
ci_w           0.92  0.91 0.95
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a `matrix` with elements as `list`.  We need `lapply/sapply`

```
sapply(output, mean)
```

-output

```
 [1] -0.046958713 -0.007220200  0.029603442  0.003012857 -0.049690575 -0.027583183  0.013375545  0.008587789  0.010594652  0.019766799
[11] -0.016020775  0.015412491
```

---

If we need the data to be in `matrix`, use `dim`

```
out <- sapply(output, mean)
dim(out) <- dim(output)
```

-output

```
> out
             [,1]         [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.046958713 -0.049690575  0.01059465
[2,] -0.007220200 -0.027583183  0.01976680
[3,]  0.029603442  0.013375545 -0.01602077
[4,]  0.003012857  0.008587789  0.01541249
```

If we need the `dimnames` as well

```
dimnames(out) <- dimnames(output)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
output <- matrix(replicate(12, rnorm(1000), simplify = FALSE), 4, 3)
```

Comment: Yes, but that way I will have problem visualizing the results. As originally I have a list of about 40 (  8 * 5 ) . I have updated how I want my output to look like.

Comment: @TriparnaPoddar try the update